# Cannot connect Oracle from AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, oracle

I need to connect on premise Oracle from AWS. There is a security group rule for the 1521 port on IP address with Oracle 19c. But the application fails, because JPA cannot open the hostname - there is a timeout.

I have written a small utility for testing:

```
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }
    }
```

And it fails too:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out, socket connect lapse 127236 ms. /10.20.30.40 1521 0 1 true
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:233)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:483)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:472)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194)
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:99)
```

I try to see all network communication, but this prints nothing:

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=all -jar oracle-test.jar jdbc:oracle:thin:user/secret@10.20.30.40:1521/DB_SVC
```

How can I find out the cause? I guess that there is some other communication I am not aware of. I am ordinary user, not root, so I cannot use advance sniffing tools.

Comment: Is this really something similar to the actual IP address?  An IP address that starts with `10.` is not routable, meaning that it can only be used in an internal network, not internet wide.

Comment: Yes, this is an internal address. We have VPN between AWS and the network.

Comment: Then it would seem that something is not right with your network configuration or routing, or perhaps a local firewall on the Oracle server is blocking the connection. You're probably going to have to get the network and/or system admins involved and trace the packets to see what's going on.

Comment: I know, that is why I posted this question. But I need to debug the issue myself and then create a new security group rule.